# Using TesseractOCR in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, tesseract, laravel-5

I'm trialing out using TesseractOCR on a new website.

I've installed a new version of Laravel (5.2.4), installed Tesseract on my server (Debian Jessie) and installed a PHP wrapper for Tesseract; [tesseract-ocr-for-php](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php).

I've followed all the setup instructions and installed the package on the application.

In my `routes.php` file I had:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
$tesseract = new TesseractOCR(asset('images/myimage.jpg'));
echo $tesseract->recognize();
});
```

Where the image `myimage.jpg` exists inside a folder called `images` inside the `public` folder.

When I navigate to `example.com/test` I get:

> ErrorException in TesseractOCR.php line 235:
>   file_get_contents(/tmp/75176598.txt): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory

According to the `readme.md` you can solve that issue by using `$tesseract->setTempDir('./my-temp-dir');`.

As such I tried changing my `routes.php` file to:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
$tesseract = new TesseractOCR(asset('images/myimage.jpg'));
$tesseract->setTempDir('/var/www/tesseract/public/images');
echo $tesseract->recognize();
});
```

However that just gives the same error with a different file path:

> ErrorException in TesseractOCR.php line 235:
>   file_get_contents(/var/www/tesseract/public/images/1770521095.txt):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

**How do I solve this error?**

Comment: Make sure your permissions are set to group read/write.

Comment: @EvilJordan I have set `/tmp/` to 777 permissions for the sake of testing it - still doesn't work. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: It's trying to pull the image from /var/www/tesseract/public/images, so that's the directory that needs the permissions.
edit: ah, i see that was your first attempt, with the /tmp directory. I am clearly wrong. apologies.

Comment: @EvilJordan The whole project has 777 permissions too.

Comment: @EvilJordan It's like it isn't creating the temp txt file to be read, but with the permissions set to 777 it should have no trouble creating it right?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is SELinux configurations... do you know if it's running?

Comment: @EvilJordan I don't think it is running? I've tried running a few commands to check but they all say the command is not found. I've tried `sestatus` and `getenforce`. How would I know for sure? I've never installed it, but it looks like it comes with Debian but is set to disabled by default.

Comment: Sounds like it's not, then. My suggestion is to see if you can get a simple php script to create tmp files. If so, then we know it's not the file system. Form there, try a simple Laravel script to the same.

Comment: i have installed this packge in to my laravel project. do i need to install My PC also ??? cause im getting nothing

Comment: @Hamelraj you need to install tesseract on your pc. Please follow the readme in the linked GitHub page. It literally covers installation...

Comment: @James ok then when we go to sever how it will work ??  confuse ?? im using Lravel framework......

Comment: You install Tesseract on each machine that needs to use it. The package provides a wrapper to be able to use Tesseract. So you install the package into your project and Tesseract on the machine and you’re good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured out that you cannot provide TesseractOCR with an HTML link to an image, it needs to be an internal file path.

As `asset()` returns a URL, I just replaced this with `public_path()` and it worked just fine.

There was never anything wrong with permissions or the actual package, just that you need to provide a file path rather than a URL.